# SAPUI5 custom app component-preload.js file code changed after moving to quality system

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I've recently migrated one of my applications from webide to VSCode environment. The app is working perfectly on development system. But after transporting the app to quality system, the component-preload.js file code is getting changed automatically. I can see trailing + signs at the end of each line.

Because of this, the componen-preload.js file is not getting loaded and the app is also not working.

screenshot of the code.

[image]

Because of this, the componen-preload.js file is not getting loaded and the app is also not working.